# detect maxthon browser javascript

Tags: javascript, maxthon

I want to detect maxthon browser in javascript, all  the properties of navigator object is same as chrome, and navigator.userAgent is also same as chrome, my maxthon browser version is 4.1.3.5000

Comment: You should rely on [feature detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(web_development)) rather than client sniffing.

Comment: just want to set opacity of an element, when browser is maxthon

Comment: Why only for this browser? Why not for every user? Or for every Chromium-based browser? (Which Maxthon is…) This type of problem is usually easier to handle, if you can identify which CSS/JS feature is missing in the targeted client and then test against this feature. See also: https://modernizr.com/